# Multiple LinearLayouts inside LinearLayout not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I have few LinearLayouts inside a LinearLayout as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_gravity="center|top"
android:padding="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Spinner
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </Spinner>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Spinner
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </Spinner>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Spinner
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </Spinner>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Spinner
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </Spinner>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

now the layout looks all fine in Design window inside Android Studio but once the app is executed the layout is displayed twice on the device - once dead (not working at all) and once working like it should.

I've had a simple TextView inside the main LinearLayout before and it worked fine, but once removed it doesn't work anymore.

I can actually remove this behavior by adding a TextView with "layout_width" and "layout_height" set to "0dp" but there has to be a proper solution. I've already tried replacing the LinearLayouts w/ RelativeLayouts but that doesn't work either.

Comment: You say that "once the app is executed the layout is displayed twice on the device", but there's no way for me to check that since you have posted java code. Could you add that to the question?

Comment: why do u have textviews with the spinner?

Comment: try changing those weights from 1 to .25

Answer (score 0):

You're setting

android:layout_weight="1"

without setting weightSum in parent LinearLayout. Is that on Purpose?

Also, I suggest you to use ConstraintLayout instead of nested LinearLayouts.

Comment: Adding weightSum to parent LinearLayout didn't help unfortunately. I'm gonna look at the ConstraintLayout, thanks for suggestion.